# Check status of process in asp.net mvc core and C# with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I created two ajax requests: one which does job (which takes longer) and another check if process is finished or not.

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dojob',
        success: function (resp) {
            addToLog(resp.length ? resp : "Ok");
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            addToLog(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}, 2000);

setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/checkstatus',
        success: function (resp) {
            addToLog(resp);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            addToLog(xhr.responseText);
        }
    })
}, 2000);
```

and the actions look like:

```
private static readonly object obj = new object();
private static bool isBusy = false;

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DoJob()
{
    lock (obj)
    {
        isBusy = true;
    }

    // does long job
    Thread.Sleep(6000);

    lock (obj)
    {
        isBusy = false;
    }

    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CheckStatus()
{
    return Ok(isBusy);
}
```

The idea is that on some point, `isBusy` indicates unexpected value (I expected that, after printing Ok, to be false, but it is still true).

How to get correctly `isBusy` when call `CheckStatus` in my situation ?

Comment: is it necessary that DoJob shouldn't be executed in parallel? i mean another shouldn't trigger DoJob if one DoJob is not finished and is still in progress?

Comment: Have you tried by changing time interval from 2000 to let say 2010 in CheckStatus call? Probably this problem is somehow related to time.